# How to make Numeric Edit Text default to blank and then use getText

Tags: android-edittext, default, gettext

Please Help!I have Edit Text field whose inputType is number. On the click of Submit button in the firstActivity I want to send the value via Bundle to next activity. I want to make the field compulsory. Before sending the value I am checking if the EditText is blank. if its blank I want to give a Toast message that "Please enter number". I am using below code line to get the numeric text

```
  editTextValue= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_attendance);
  editTextValue.setText("0");
  var1 = Integer.valueOf((editTextValue.getText().toString()));
```

For this code to work I have to first set the default value to 0
But due to this when user is entering value in this EditText, he has to first erase 0 and then enter number. I dont want to set it to 0 value. Is there any other way to make this work.

Below is my Code in XML:

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
        android:layout_width="100sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:hint="0"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

FirstActivity.java

```
onCreate(){
 editTextValue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_1);

 editTextValue.setText("0");


  btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        var1 = Integer.valueOf((editTextValue.getText()
                    .toString()));

         if (var1 == 0) // when no value is entered
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter value",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         else
         {
              Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        SecondActivity.class);


                dataBundle.putInt(SecondActivity.VAR1,var1);
                i.putExtras(dataBundle);
                startActivity(i);

         }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code worked for me:

```
// editTextValue.setText("0");

    editTextValue.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                KeyEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {

                var1 = Integer.valueOf((editTextValue
                        .getText().toString()));

            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```